What would the exhaust of a decelerating antimatter rocket look like to an observer on Earth?
Setup; The year is 1922 and an armada of roughly 1000 Starships, each over 2 kilometers long, has begun its decelerating burn from 90% the speed of light, at a pace of 150 m/s². Their destination ? Earth, obviously.
Q; What does Humanity see ?

My initial picture was the classic Sci-Fi one. A bright blue star in the sky which slowly grows bigger and brighter, eventually outshining the Moon by orders of magnitude, bathing the Earth below in light, before the engines shut down.
While this is a very pretty picture, the more i look into it the less plausible this seems.
For a start, the incoming armada would not be a point light source for long. If we argue each Vehicle uses straight Antimatter annihilation for its propulsion, then they have to be spaced apart by 100s if not 1000s of kilometers to avoid a catastrophic cascade in the event of a single failure. So chances are, by the time the armada gets to the Moon, the square it spans in the sky is many times larger than Earth.
The more problematic aspect is that high energy Antimatter annihilation, such as the one proposed for propulsion, does not produce visible radiation. Roughly 30% of the Annihilations energy goes into Gamma Rays. More broadly, most energy goes into Ionizing radiation (Including Gamma rays obviously). Thrust is produced by deflecting the charged particles created in the annihilation process, like subatomic particles. And these exhaust products are not visible.
Of course this is all very idealized. In reality some fraction of the Antimatter does not instantly annihilate, the engine bell will degrade over time and weird interactions between subatomic particles (for example when they recombine to form atoms) might create visible light. But under the line it really seems like not a lot would be produced.
Which again raises the question, what would people actually see ? If anything.
Right now my top guess is that they would not see anything until the Armada is much closer. The engines spew an unfathomable amount of ionizing radiation broadly at Earth. The armada begins to decelerate roughly 0.15 Ly from Earth, i would guess at such a great distance the radiation would have diffused enough to avoid major effects on Earth. But eventually the armada gets close enough for the radiation to interact with Earths magnetic field and the Ionosphere. Initially we might see a faint Aurora on the side of the planet facing the armada. Eventually this may become a global one. In the final hours of the deceleration burn, the Ionosphere may start to glow. Though it might not, assumably the engines are not pointed directly at Earth to avoid irradiating every square centimeter of the planet.
All of this only applies if the armada does not inject anything into the exhaust and runs on pure Annihilation. Which is what i am going with.
Yet i cant help but feel underwhelmed. The great blue star in the sky has been reduced to a source of simply ungodly amounts of radiation silently approaching an unsuspecting Earth. Surly i am missing some phenomena that would make the vehicles exhaust visible, at least to an Earthly observer ? Then 1920s, being where they are along the linear track of time, are far removed from the 1960s when we were first able to observe Gamma Rays. So it seems the only answer here is "They wouldn't see anything until the god damn atmosphere begins to glow"
Thanks for reading and any help !

The matter-antimatter annihilation reaction produces high energy photons, that's correct. But high energy photons are basically useless for propulsion. There must be some unspecified other part of the engine which takes the high energy photons and does something with them; and it is this other part of thre engine which gets hot and emits visible light or infrared etc. Think of a nuclear-powered ship or submarine: the nuclear reactor makes heat, and then there is the rest of the plant which uses it to boil water to make steam to turn the turbines to turn the generators to feed the motors...

@AlexP Annihilation produces charged particles which are deflected by a magnetic nozzle. That produces the thrust.

if they are decelerating to intersect earth, they are not pointing their exhaust directly at earth, because earth is moving!

@ths very true ! So yeah, at this point even if the radioactive beam of death emitted from each ship would create atmospheric effects at distance, Earth is not in the way. So there just wouldnt be anything visible.

If you're ejecting charged particles with an engine that can work at the ISP required (note: your mass ratio gets pretty crazy even with antimatter if you want to cruise at .9c) I would think you would see something as those particles interact with the interstellar medium.

@AlexP Hi energy phots are perfectly useful for propulsion, as while photons do not carry mass, they have momentum. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_rocket

Seems like you are using visible light. Switch to infared and an antimatter drive would be the brightest thing in the solar system, brighter a fusion drive.

If you've got antimatter-annihilation, you're probably not generating just photons. You've probably got enough heat to do pair-production on occasion - meaning there's still going to be an exhaust plume of extremely hot plasma. It might not be as dense as expected for a conventional rocket, but should still be visible.

There's nothing wrong with not seeing anything. In fact, it's a good thing.
Frankly, it would make for a better story because detecting the incoming fleet must be something done indirectly. Gamma rays were discovered in 1900 by Paul Villard, but the first practical detection was 1914 by Rutherford and Andrade. By 1922 there would be no practical detection of such a small source as your incoming armada.
But what gamma rays do to our atmosphere might be detectable and, of course, could be in your story.  Something unusual is happening that didn't happen in Real History, which leads to the plausible conclusion that someone noticed that unusual thing.

Treat the output of the engines like a Gamma Ray Burst causing atmospheric changes in a localized manner (i.e., strangely occurring only on the side of Earth directly below point "X" in the sky).

Being ionizing radiation we can assume...



A greater concentration of radioactive molecules in the affected atmosphere (energetic ionization can make a particle radioactive).
A bluish-purple ionized air glow that's most intense below point "X".
Airplanes (this is a bit of a stretch for the time period) would encounter greater static electricity discharges in the affected area and radio through the area would be severely disrupted.
A higher incidence of cancer (the modern model for which was developed by De Morgan in the 1870s, so it would be well known if not yet particularly well understood) would occur in those areas exposed to the gamma rays.


Ozone depletion leading to harmful UV consequences (from sunburns to crop problems, even mutations) — but (as with the other issues) it curiously occurs only in specific patterns.

We know today that there's no life on Mars, but in the 1920s?
Let's add some curiosity to our mystery. Statisticians start putting together all that previously mentioned data and discover that the gamma radiation can't be coming from the sun. It's not even enough and doesn't span the earth in a diurnal pattern. So they start looking to the skies! And what's the first thing they imagine?
The Martians are attacking!
Civilized life on Mars had its adherents well into the 20th century. Author Edgar Rice Burroughs made good on this general belief with his Barsoom (John Carter) books. People kept looking at those lines and thinking they were massive canals full of water. This is really good for you! Because you have the ability to tie the incoming fictional armada into the Real History discovery that there is, in fact, no life on Mars. Scientists can prove two things by looking at Mars much more closely:

The confirmed discovery that there's no life on Mars. (Curious tertiatry effect: Burroughs wouldn't write the second half of the Barsoom books. They were written in the 1940s, by which time Martian life would have been thoroughly disproven and interest in the stories waned.)

The pattern of damage on the Earth does not relate to the two planetary orbits. It can only be true if the gamma ray source was a fixed point right over there.


Embrace the mystery, my friend, a glorious point of light robs you of a lot of storytelling potential
I recognize that the story you want to tell is the story of the armada and, I conclude, an invasion of Earth. Bully! But part of what made H.G. Wells' The War of the Worlds so popular was that there were two stories within the story: the physical attack and the secondary, unseen science that solved the problem. Always look to copy the masters, my friend.
No visible engine output is a proverbial godsend. It means humanity must figure out what's happening without direct evidence of it. That's actually a very common thing in the world of scientific discovery. So common, in fact, that several people have been tapped for the authorship of the now famous phrase...

The most exciting phrase to hear in science, the one that heralds new discoveries, is not “Eureka!” (I found it!) but “That’s funny …”

What many worldbuilders don't realize is that a good story is the most valuable marketing tool for your world. Tell a bad story and nobody will care that the world you built was marvelous or that the details you've included, amazing. I was a micropublisher for ten years. Believe me. A good story will sell a bad world, but a good world will not sell a bad story. On the other hand, a good story combined with a good world can make you a fortune.
A few more notes
From your question, I noted the ideas of widely distributed gamma radiation and widely distributed ships.

My purpose in pointing out Gammma Ray Bursts is that in the context of Real Science, they come from other galaxies. That's a whole lot further away than your armada, and yet the burst is cohesive enough to be detectable here. I don't believe you need worry about your gamma rays spreading out too much. Besides, if they really are, you have a lousy engine design as the further off-axis the radiation spillage, the less efficient your engines.

While your ships must be that far apart during relativistic flight, being that far apart on approach to Earth makes no sense. There'd be no way for the majority of the fleet to enter Earth's orbit. In fact, most of them would pass through our solar system. By the time your fleet reaches the orbit of the moon, they had better be a whole lot closer together such that all of the fleet can enter Earth's orbit. More likely, they'd be concentrated into a band the thickness of the equatorial region defined by the two Tropics (Cancer and Capricorn), but staged front-to-back such that the armada can enter Earth's orbit over the course of 24 hours covering the entire circumference of the planet to ensure full telemetry and coverage. For devastation purposes, dontchaknow.

Finally, not having put that much effort into the design of antimatter engines, one would think that there'd be a point where the "population" of space craft is too dense to use those engines. A bit like the shuttle in Tom Cruise's film Oblivion, which had in-atmosphere engines and space engines. There must come a point when those engines must be shut down and more traditional engines used... or you either minimize the density of approaching ships (not much of an armada) or you maximize the time required to insert everyone into orbit. Or you cook the crew of another ship. Yes, you could argue that the ships have shielding to protect them from that purpose — but so few worldbuilders consider economy when they build their worlds. Good engineering would use only as much expensive shielding as is necessary and rely on inner-system engines that don't pump out deadly gamma rays. Why? Because who knows what might be in the path of those engines. Satellites come to mind (on the home planet) or some hapless astronaut who had to go outside to fix an antenna. Even Roddenberry knew enough to know there'd have to be two engines.



This is a very insightful comment. Thank you.
I have already written Act I and II, III and IV dont change with any of these alterations. The whole idea is that Humanity, like in TWOTW, simply loses.
It does however change I and II in ways ill need some time to understand. It mainly shifts the conflict. Prior, with the big blue star, people knew something was coming. Now they dont.
The idea of a goose-chase to determine the anomalies origin is, however, very appealing. And it seems, overall, much more interesting to show humanity slowly realizing something is coming.

They use beam core antimatter rockets that accelerate the matter/antimatter particles before annihilating them and further focusing the charged annihilation products with a magnetic nozzle. This directly produces some thrust, enables use of the mass that ends up as neutral particles for doing so, and red-shifts the forward component of the gamma emissions down to the visible range where the ship can more easily deal with them. Some of these are absorbed to produce power, the rest are reflected aft to produce a bit more thrust and to reduce heating of the ship.
So, there is a relatively tightly collimated beam of charged pions and their decay products, a less-collimated beam of gamma and other neutral annihilation products, and a halo of reflected light. Early in braking this will be blue-shifted back out of the visible range by the ship's own motion, but it will become visible again as the ship decelerates.
Additionally, portions of a drive operating at such high power levels are likely to be hot enough to be brightly incandescent. While dimmer, these would likely be more visible earlier in the deceleration, when the infrared portion is blue shifted into the visible range.

Interesting approach. Assuming an exhaust velocity of around 0.99c, the redshift factor, as seen from earth, is 0.0325. So roughly speaking, anything hotter than ~50 Kelvin would visibly glow at 1500 Kelvin (as seen from Earth). At 200 Kelvin, the apparent temperature would be hotter than the surface of the sun. Ill have to look into just how bright these blueshifted elements might get. But thanks a lot for the ideas !

Good News - It's a Bright Blue Wall!

Thrust is produced by deflecting the charged particles created in the annihilation process, like subatomic particles (OP)

Well, if you put a bunch of pieces of matter (like subatomic particles) in a soup of high energy photons (like gamma rays) then the matter will heat up. Matter that is hot emits black body radiation.
Since red is at the low energy side of the visible spectrum and blue is at the high energy side, we'd expect things that are kind of hot to glow red (think iron in a forge) and things that are really hot to glow blue (think, brightest stars)
So I would expect your anti-matter engines to produce an absolutely brilliant blue cone of radiation and charged particles. And you're probably putting out enough energy to ionize and accelerate the interstellar gas and dust that your cone of destruction interacts with, so even if your ships are relatively close together, they will create a miles wide area of concentrated, extremely hot gas that will glow as well.
Kind of creating their own ad hoc astrophysical jet.
As the matter drifts out of your radiation cone, it would eventually cool down. So you may have a central blue shaft with rainbows in every direction as the temperature drops off towards red.

The matter-antimatter annihillation would be pretty much invisible, but what about the shielding that prevents damage to the ships while flying at very high speed through space?
You're probably going to have some sort of energy shield at least in the front of your ships to prevent collisions with micro meteoroids and other objects that can't be avoided. If you think up the technology behind that cleverly enough, those shields may well glow brightly in visible light simply from collisions with interstellar dust and hydrogen as it gets caught and deflected. Brems radiation may do the trick.
It's however highly unlikely anyone on earth would identify this as approaching alien spacecraft as the light source would grow dimmer as the ships get closer and slow down (thus the relative luminosity would stay pretty much the same until it completely blinks out). At most someone might get excited about having discovered a new star.

"but what about the shielding that prevents damage to the ships while flying at very high speed through space?"
Fair point. The armada is made of Waterskiing type rockets, so the payload sits below the engines to save weight. Presumably you need some serious ablative heat management system / shielding just for the cable to not instantly disappear from this plane of existence.
So the visible exhaust may just be that ablative shielding being ionized.
On the protection against meteoroids. I think they would use Lasers, which might be visible if pointed at earth.

@ErikHall I don't think there's shielding in existence that can handle the energy involved.  Note that the particles slamming into it will hit with plenty of energy to cause fusion.  It won't be a heated layer outside the spacecraft like it is when a space capsule comes home, effectively all of the energy appears inside your shield (or inside your spacecraft if the shield isn't thick enough.) We aren't remotely close to building something that can stand up to that and most likely will never be.

@LorenPechtel if we're having anti-matter drives we can have such shield tech as well. We may even need it for the anti-matter containment.
